# 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta' in Django

Tags: python, django

I am writing a website and when the user logs in, I get this error - 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'. How do I fix it?
Here is a structure of my project:

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───ithogwarts
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   settings.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│
├───main
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │
│   ├───static
│   │   └───main
│   │       ├───css
│   │       │       footer.css
│   │       │       header.css
│   │       │       index.css
│   │       │
│   │       ├───img
│   │       │
│   │       └───js
│   │               script.js
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───main
│   │           index.html
│   │           layout.html
│   │           level_magic.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│
├───templates
│   └───registration
└───users
    │   admin.py
    │   apps.py
    │   forms.py
    │   models.py
    │   tests.py
    │   urls.py
    │   utils.py
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───migrations
    │   │   0001_initial.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    │   │
    │   └───__pycache__
    │
    ├───static
    │   └───users
    │       └───css
    │               login.css
    │               register.css
    │
    ├───templates
    │   └───users
    │           login.html
    │           register.html
    │
    └───__pycache__
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginUserForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(label="Почта", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'login__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'введите вашу почту'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Пароль", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'login__form-title form-control',
                                                                          'placeholder': 'введите пароль'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('username')
```

views.py:

```
class LoginUser(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginUserForm
    template_name = 'users/login.html'
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 63, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 92, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 126, in login
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
  File "C:\Users\belog\ithogwarts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 241, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/login
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ ᅠ

Comment: Please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this go to your settings and add AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Myapp' to the bottom